# Remote Wildcard script mapping from site in IIS 7.5 with powershell

Tags: windows, iis, scripting, powershell, iis-7.5

I created a site in IIS 7.5 via Powershell; however, the site inherited the parent handler mappings and one of the wildcard script mappings causes problems for this particular application.  Is there a way to script removing a wildcard script mapping?

Comment: Do you need to do this from a script or IIS MMC?

Comment: I need to do it from a script because I need the setup of the site to be 100% hands-off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion.  I actually found a command that does exactly what I need:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config "<SITE_NAME>" -section:system.webServer/handlers /-"[name='<NAME_OF_HANDLER_MAPPING']"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have imported the module `WebAdministration`, you can use the `Set-ItemProperty` command on the `IIS:` drive, such as:

```
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site" -name "Bindings" -value  @{protocol="HTTP";port="80"}
```

Note that this will *replace* all of your site bindings, so you will need to enter each one that you want to have in the `value` parameter.